# How to pass dynamic search parameters from client through RIA Services?

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services

I have a C#.NET Silverlight 3.0 client running RIA Services with an EF model. I'm trying to set up an advanced search system on the client such that the user can say, I want field (property) "Foo1" to have value "Bar1," etc.. .

I'd like to use a flexible, dynamic approach similar to [this one](http://blog.bvsoftware.com/post/2008/02/27/How-to-create-a-Dynamic-LINQ-Query-Programmatically.aspx). The problem is I can't pass IQueryable as a ServiceOperation parameter or as a domain service parameter. I.E. This doesn't work:

```
[ServiceOperation()]
public int GetFooCount(string category, IQueryable<Foo> search)
{
    int fooCount;
    if (search != null)
    {
        IQueryable<Foo> filteredFooSet = this.Context.FooSet.Intersect(search);
        fooCount = (from foo in filteredFooSet
                    where foo.Category == category
                    select foo).Count();
    }
    else
    {
        fooCount = (from foo in this.Context.ContactSet
                    where foo.Category == category
                    select foo).Count();
    }

    return fooCount;
}
```

Can anyone suggest either a way to get this approach to work or an alternative (better) approach? The objective is a flexible search control that can be applied to more than any single specific entity type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to use [the Dynamic Linq Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). Using that library you could pass your where clauses as string and then use the library to use that against your EF data.